Mi botón con texto oculto muestra el texto al iniciar el sitio
Tengo un sitio creado con bootstrap. Cree 3 cards para poner 3 servicios que se ofrecen pero el texto que es la descripción del servicio lo quiero ocultar. Esto lo hice con una función en JavaScript. El problema es que de las tres, la primera card muestra la descripción por defecto. Actualmente al entrar al website se muestra así:

Este es mi código en HTML de ese pedazo:


function muestra_oculta(id) {
  let div = document.getElementById(id);
  if (div.style.display == "flex") {
    div.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    div.style.display = "flex";
  }
}
/* CARDS SERVICES */

#contenido1 {
  display: none;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#contenido2 {
  display: none;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#contenido3 {
  display: none;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--SERVICES-->
<section>
  <div id="services" class="container mt-3 mb-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="card" style="width: 100%">
          <img src="//placehold.it/500x300/" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">System Diagnostic</h5>
            <div id="contenido1">
              <p class="card-text">Includes:</p>
              <br>
              <ul>
                <li>Complete diagnostic on your AC System.</li>
                <li>Solutions to resolve the problem.</li>
                <li>Diagnostic fee will be waived with repair.</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <button onclick='muestra_oculta("contenido1")' class="btn btn-primary" form="contenido1">+</button>
            <a role="button" class="btn btn-primary" href="https://www.google.com">Book Now</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="card" style="width: 100%">
          <img src="//placehold.it/500x300/fa5/fff" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">A/C Tune Up</h5>
            <div id="contenido2">
              <p class="card-text">Includes:</p>
              <br>
              <ul>
                <li>Check and adjust thermostat as needed.</li>
                <li>Check filter.</li>
                <li>Check voltages.</li>
              </ul>
              <p class="card-text">Includes outdoor condenser coil rinse.</p>
              <p class="card-text"><strong>$55.00 For Each Additional Unit</strong></p>
              <p class="card-text">When tune up is complete, you will receive a recommendation for any further maintenance or repair needs of your system.</p>
            </div>
            <br>
            <button onclick='muestra_oculta("contenido2")' class="btn btn-primary" form="contenido2">+</button>
            <a role="button" class="btn btn-primary" href="https://www.google.com">Book Now</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="card" style="width: 100%">
          <img src="//placehold.it/500x300/c9c/fff" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Free Estimate</h5>
            <div id="contenido3">
              <p class="card-text">Includes:</p>
              <br>
              <br>
              <p class="card-text"><strong>FREE ESTIMATE 2ND OPINION</strong></p>
              <p class="card-text">Equipment is subject to change due to shortages and availability.</p>
            </div>
            <br>
            <button onclick='muestra_oculta("contenido3")' class="btn btn-primary" form="contenido3">+</button>
            <a role="button" class="btn btn-primary" href="https://www.google.com">Book Now</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>




Hola Daniella,  bienvenida, tanto los códigos como los mensajes de error y explicaiciones, deben estar en formato texto, sino, te cerrarán la pregunta, te sugiero que la edites y hagas las correcciones necesarias.

He hecho el código ejecutable y parece que funciona sin problemas. ¿Puede haber algo más que esté afectando este comoprtamiento?

a ver que podemos hacer.... espero no confundirte y espero darte la solucion vamos:
a grandes rasgos..puede ser elestilo display o si la propiedad style.display entonces vamos a modificar un poco el Javascript, modifica la funcion muestra_oculta para verificar el estado display correctamente tambien donde style.display no tiene valor
function muestra_oculta(id) {
    let div = document.getElementById(id);
    // revisa si display es "flex""block" o esta vacio
    if (div.style.display === "flex" || div.style.display === "block" || div.style.display === "") {
        div.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        div.style.display = "flex";
    }
}

ahora veamos que los contenidos esten ocultos al cargar la web.. agrega un script que se ejecute cuando la pagina se haya cargado completamente:
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('contenido1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('contenido2').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('contenido3').style.display = 'none';
};

el orden de carga es importante que el script que contiene la función muestra_oculta se cargue justo antes del cierre de la etiqueta body..

<script src="ruta/script.js"></script>
</body>


ahora vamos con el css que parece estar bien .. asegurandonos de que esten ocultos :
#contenido1,
#contenido2,
#contenido3 {
    display: none;
    flex-flow: wrap;
}

corre tu proyecto.. si no funciona puede ser que haya otro javascript o css que este afectando directamentye el estado del display.. o lo que seria mas comun estoy totalmente equivocao
espero que todo salga bien y haya podido ayudar
